# ~ selector to remove more than one element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove all specific element types AFTER the `<h1>Title</h1>` element, but still keep some element types:

```
    <h1>Keep</h1>
    <br />
    <label>Keep</label><br />
    <label>Keep</label><br />
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <br />
    <label>Remove</label><br />
    <input type="text" value="remove" /><br />
    <input type="text" value="remove" /><br />
    <label>Remove></label><br />
    <input type="text" value="remove" /><br />
    <p>Remove</p>
    <br />
    <hr />Keep <span>Keep</span>
```

My current code works perfectly:

```
    $('h1:contains("Title")').prev('br').remove();
    $('h1:contains("Title") ~ br').remove();
    $('h1:contains("Title") ~ label').remove();
    $('h1:contains("Title") ~ input[type="text"]').remove();
    $('h1:contains("Title") ~ p').remove();
    $('h1:contains("Title")').remove();
```

But I'm looking for a way to condense it in the most efficient way.

Using `$('h1:contains("Title") ~ br, label, input[type="text"], p)` does not seem to select those elements, instead, it selects all of those types of elements on the page.

Expected output:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<hr />Keep <span>Keep</span>
```

Comment: It might be more efficient to `.not()` select certain elements, in this case. Better yet, consider restructuring the HTML so that all the removable elements are wrapped up in a single `<div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nextUntil` method:

```
$('h1:contains("Title")').nextUntil('hr').remove();
```

If you want to remove the `h1` element too:

```
$('h1:contains("Title")').nextUntil('hr').addBack().remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLHVF/

Comment: This selector also targets the `<span>Keep</span>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can trim back a few selectors by saving the title element to a jQuery object:

```
var title = $('h1:contains("Title")');
$(title).prev('br').remove();
$(' ~ br, ~ label, ~ input[type="text"], ~ p', title).remove();
$(title).remove();
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating this (with red backgrounds instead of removing the elements): http://jsfiddle.net/cetNE/

It's a fairly simple way to approach this, and it's pretty easy to see what you're doing in the code.